# Twilio message with NodeJS and Sequelize mySQL

Tags: jquery, node.js, sms, twilio, sequelize.js

I am trying to fire a welcome message to a user whenever they submit a form to join, I'm using Node. JS and the Twilio code I have worked when I run it independently, but I want to be able to send a message to the user that has just submitted the form and not only to one certain phone number.
So I inserted the Twilio outbound message code inside the jQuery code that handles submitting user's data. No error and data are still submitted and rendered(handleFormSubmit function is fired) but no messages were sent. I cannot run node user.js because it doesn't recognize jQuery $. How do I get the messages to send, is there a better way or am I missing something in the logic. Here is my user.js file (about the commented out code, that's me trying to put the function diff places)

// Get references to page elements

```
var $userName = $("#username");
var $userEmail = $("#user-email-address");
var $userPassword = $("#user-password");
var $phonenumber = $("#phonenum");
var $profilePicUrl = $("#profile-photo");
var $firstName = $("#first-name");
var $lastName = $("#last-name");
var $gender = $("#gender");
var $DOB = $("#DOB");
var $hometown = $("#hometown");
var $bio = $("#bio");
var $languages = $("#languages");
var $whyOn = $("#why-on");
var $oneAThing = $("#one-A-thing");
var $hobby = $("#hobby");
var $countries = $("#countries-lived");
var $whatIShare = $("#what-I-share");
var $interests = $("#user-interests");
// var $guideStatus = $("#guideStatus");
var $submitBtnU = $("#submitU");
var $userList = $("#user-list");

const accountSid = "ACdxxxxxxbx1axxxxxxxxxxx3";
const authToken = "exxxxxx7xxxxxxxxxxxxx8";  //sensored the token out :)

const client = require("twilio")(accountSid, authToken);

// The API object contains methods for each kind of request we'll make
var API = {
  saveUser: function (user) {
    return $.ajax({
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      type: "POST",
      url: "api/users",
      data: JSON.stringify(user)
    });
  },
  getUsers: function () {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "api/users",
      type: "GET"
    });
  },
  editUsers: function (id) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "api/users/" + id,
      type: "PUT"
    });
  },
  deleteUser: function (id) {
    return $.ajax({
      url: "api/users/" + id,
      type: "DELETE"
    });
  }
};
//send message func
var sendMessage = function () {
  API.getUsers().then(function (data) {
    var twiliosms = data.map(function (user) {
      console.log("something", user.phonenumber)
      client.messages.create({
        to: '+' + user.phonenumber,
        from: '+12245077001', //this is the purchased number
        body: 'Welcome to localize'
      })
        .then((message) => console.log(message.sid))
        .done();

      return twiliosms;
    });

  });
};

// refreshExamples gets new examples from the db and repopulates the list
var refreshUsers = function () {
  API.getUsers().then(function (data) {
    var $users = data.map(function (user) {
      var $a = $("<a>")
        .text(user.user_name)
        .attr("href", "/user/" + user.id);

      var $li = $("<li>")
        .attr({
          class: "list-group-item",
          "data-id": user.id
        })
        .append($a);

      var $button = $("<button>")
        .addClass("btn btn-danger float-right delete")
        .text("ｘ");

      $li.append($button);

      return $li;
    });
    // var twiliosms = data.map(function(user) {
    //   client.messages
    //     .create({
    //       to: user.phonenumber,
    //       from: "+12245077001", //this is the purchased number
    //       body: "Welcome to localize"
    //     })
    //     .then(message => console.log(message.sid))
    //     .done();

    //   return twiliosms;
    // });

    $userList.empty();
    $userList.append($users);

  });
  location.reload();
};

// handleFormSubmit is called whenever we submit a new user
// Save the new user to the db and refresh the list
var handleFormSubmit = function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var user = {
    user_name: $userName.val().trim(),
    email: $userEmail.val().trim(),
    password: $userPassword.val(),
    phonenumber: $phonenumber.val(),
    profile_pic_url: $profilePicUrl.val(),
    first_name: $firstName.val(),
    last_name: $lastName.val(),
    gender: $gender.val(),
    DOB: $DOB.val(),
    hometown: $hometown.val(),
    bio: $bio.val(),
    languages: $languages.val(),
    whyOn: $whyOn.val(),
    one_Athing: $oneAThing.val(),
    hobby: $hobby.val(),
    countries: $countries.val(),
    what_I_share: $whatIShare.val(),
    // guide_status : $guideStatus.val(),
    interests: $interests.val()
  };
  // var twiliosms = data.map(function (user) {
  //   console.log("something",user.phonenumber)
  //   client.messages.create({
  //       to: '+' + user.phonenumber,
  //       from: '+12345356731', //this is the purchased number
  //       body: 'Welcome to localize'
  //   })
  //   .then((message) => console.log(message.sid))
  //   .done();

  //   return twiliosms;
  // });
  // if (!(user.userName && user.userEmail)) {
  //   alert("You must enter a valid username and email address!");
  //   return;
  // }
  sendMessage();

  API.saveUser(user).then(function () {
    refreshUsers();
  });

  $userName.val("");
  $userEmail.val("");
  $userPassword.val("");
  $phonenumber.val("");
  $profilePicUrl.val("");
  $firstName.val("");
  $lastName.val("");
  $gender.val("");
  $DOB.val("");
  $hometown.val("");
  $bio.val("");
  $languages.val("");
  $whyOn.val("");
  $oneAThing.val("");
  $hobby.val("");
  $countries.val("");
  $whatIShare.val("");
  $interests.val("");
};



// handleDeleteBtnClick is called when an example's delete button is clicked
// Remove the example from the db and refresh the list
var handleDeleteBtnClick = function () {
  var idToDelete = $(this)
    .parent()
    .attr("data-id");

  API.deleteUser(idToDelete).then(function () {
    refreshUsers();
  });
};

// var handleEditBtnClick = function () {
//   var idToEdit = $(this)
//     .parent()
//     .attr("data-id");

//   API.editUser(idToEdit).then(function () {
//     refreshUsers();
//   });
// };

// Add event listeners to the submit and delete buttons
$submitBtnU.on("click", handleFormSubmit);
$userList.on("click", ".delete", handleDeleteBtnClick);
// $editProfile. on("click", ".edit", handleEditBtnClick);
```

Comment: Hi, Twilio provide a log of all the requests that were made. You can check there. This happens to me as well with my number. But DND is activated on my number hence not receiving sms. To cope with this you need to create a ticket on twilio telling them, you do not send promotional sms etc stuffs and they can enable your twilio number to send sms to dnd numbers as well.

Comment: Also from your code are you appending country code to the number? Eg for India it would be -  +91xyz

Comment: I did have the country code included and the number i was testing was also verified with Twilio properly, I just cant find a way to get this code to fire after the form is being submitted..suspecting the location of the function being called.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make your API request to Twilio from the client side of your application, is that right or is some of this on the server side?

Comment: from the client side and thats probably where the issue is I'll have to find a way to integrate it to server side